# How to implement Google Photos feature of zooming to relayout image thumbnails

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, recyclerview-layout

In the Google Photos app, we can see the photos grouped by the day, month or year that they were taken.

To switch between the grouping modes, they have a great responsive animation where the size of the items in the grid changes according to the current pinch.

I have easily figured out how to create the individual grouping screens using RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager. However, I don't have any ideas about how to achieve the smooth transition animation that exists to switch between them.

Can anybody provide an idea of where to begin?

On idea I had was having the other grouping screens always ready in two more RecyclerViews and crossfade between them on a pinch action. But this is not how Google Photos does it because I can see that the same View is getting reused/rearranged to display the new screen.